# Trying to integrate PostForm with React Function

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using a Creative Tim Template for my react project where I have a login template (code is as follows):

```
import React from "react";

// reactstrap components
import {
  Button,
  Card,
  CardHeader,
  CardBody,
  CardFooter,
  Form,
  Input,
  InputGroupAddon,
  InputGroupText,
  InputGroup,
  Container,
  Col
} from "reactstrap";

// core components
import ExamplesNavbar from "components/Navbars/ExamplesNavbar.js";
import TransparentFooter from "components/Footers/TransparentFooter.js";

function LoginPage() {
  const [firstFocus, setFirstFocus] = React.useState(false);
  const [lastFocus, setLastFocus] = React.useState(false);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    document.body.classList.add("login-page");
    document.body.classList.add("sidebar-collapse");
    document.documentElement.classList.remove("nav-open");
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    document.body.scrollTop = 0;
    return function cleanup() {
      document.body.classList.remove("login-page");
      document.body.classList.remove("sidebar-collapse");
    };
  });
  return (
    <>
      <ExamplesNavbar />
      <div className="page-header clear-filter" filter-color="blue">
        <div
          className="page-header-image"
          style={{
            backgroundImage: "url(" + require("assets/img/login.jpg") + ")"
          }}
        ></div>
        <div className="content">
          <Container>
            <Col className="ml-auto mr-auto" md="4">
              <Card className="card-login card-plain">
                <Form action="" className="form" method="">
                  <CardHeader className="text-center">
                  </CardHeader>
                  <CardBody>
                    <InputGroup
                      className={
                        "no-border input-lg" +
                        (firstFocus ? " input-group-focus" : "")
                      }
                    >
                      <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
                        <InputGroupText>
                          <i className="now-ui-icons ui-1_email-85"></i>
                        </InputGroupText>
                      </InputGroupAddon>
                      <Input
                        placeholder="Email"
                        type="text"
                        onFocus={() => setFirstFocus(true)}
                        onBlur={() => setFirstFocus(false)}
                      ></Input>
                    </InputGroup>
                    <InputGroup
                      className={
                        "no-border input-lg" +
                        (lastFocus ? " input-group-focus" : "")
                      }
                    >
                      <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
                        <InputGroupText>
                          <i className="now-ui-icons ui-1_lock-circle-open"></i>
                        </InputGroupText>
                      </InputGroupAddon>
                      <Input
                        placeholder="Password"
                        type="text"
                        onFocus={() => setLastFocus(true)}
                        onBlur={() => setLastFocus(false)}
                      ></Input>
                    </InputGroup>
                  </CardBody>
                  <CardFooter className="text-center">
                    <Button
                      block
                      className="btn-round"
                      color="info"
                      href="#pablo"
                      onClick={e => e.preventDefault()}
                      size="lg"
                    >
                      Get Started
                    </Button>
                    <div className="pull-right">
                      <h6>
                        <a
                          className="link"
                          href="#pablo"
                          onClick={e => e.preventDefault()}
                        >
                          Need Help?
                        </a>
                      </h6>
                    </div>
                  </CardFooter>
                </Form>
              </Card>
            </Col>
          </Container>
        </div>
        <TransparentFooter />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default LoginPage;
```

Separately, I was able to implement a PostForm.js but it is in a Class format (code is as follows): \

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

class PostForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: ''
        }
    }

    changeHandler = (e) => {
        this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value })
    }

    submitHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log(this.state)
        axios.post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', this.state)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })
    }

    render() {
        const {email, password} = this.state
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" name="email" value={email} onChange={this.changeHandler} />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="password" name="password" value={password} onChange={this.changeHandler} />
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default PostForm
```

I was trying to integrate the two where I can post username and password using axios but in the Creative Tim function based template. Can anyone help me figure out how to integrate this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import your component into the other module `import PostForm from ...` and add `<PostForm />` to the JSX in the template where you need it.

You probably want to give your component a better name as well, since it is posting to the server. But it seems like you actually want to login, food for thought.

Comment: Thanks for that. When I try to import, I get the following error: Module not found: You attempted to import /components/Login/PostForm.js which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.

Comment: You'll need to add your components into the src folder! Simple as that. Let me know if that gives you trouble.